receiving the following Chainlink error: cannot estimate gas
We are facing problem when calling openAI API with chainlink function, we are testing on the repo from Constellation last year and YouTube
The issue is when i an runing 04_request.js from scripts folder, it show Error, the error is

reason: 'cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit',
code: 'UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT',"`

follow are some error code

Error making the Functions Request :  <ref *1> Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT ] (error={"reason":"cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit","code":"UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT","error":{"reason":"processing response error","code":"SERVER_ERROR","body":"{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"error":{"code":3,"message":"execution reverted","data":"0x1d70f87a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000493e0"}}\n","error":{"code":3,"data":"0x1d70f87a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000493e0"},"requestBody":"0x////very long data/////,"requestMethod":"POST","url":"https://api-sepolia.etherscan.io/api"},"method":"estimateGas","transaction":{"from":"0xd83Cb0fe58Afc5A54fa7771ea988CdF3E1d89730","maxPriorityFeePerGas":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x59682f00"},"maxFeePerGas":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x1d28c1e9e8"},"to":"0x266d3f1df7fc27047e1a38eBAFa6B71bf5c6b391","data":"0x///very long data////,"to":{},"from":"0xd83Cb0fe58Afc5A54fa7771ea988CdF3E1d89730","type":2,"maxFeePerGas":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x1d28c1e9e8"},"maxPriorityFeePerGas":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x59682f00"},"nonce":{},"gasLimit":{},"chainId":{}}, code=UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT, version=abstract-signer/5.7.0)

and it repeat several times(this is the one i change provider as follow), and the one i try with Alchemy shows the same error
It seems to be address issue or logic issue in code, but i follow step by step of the video and very sure that i didn't mess up  address, the only thing unsure is that i am using Alchemy for RPC URL is it available, i even change the provider in connection.js to
const provider = new providers.EtherscanProvider("sepolia",process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY);

enter image description here
and encryptedSecretsRef generate by 03_secrets.js in the scripts folder
my wallet address is 0xd83Cb0fe58Afc5A54fa7771ea988CdF3E1d89730
thx for the help

Can you share the repo you are testing? The link is to the Chainlink github rather than a specific project.

This error can sometimes be thrown by the EVM when there are config errors. Config errors can be things like incorrect subscription id, no subscription LINK, the consumer contract is not added as a subscription consumer, incorrect router address etc.  Please double check the pre-requisites to making a request.
